# Can I Use models class since other file create manually?

Tags: python, django, django-models

the files are

```
app
       __init__.py
       admin.py
       import.py
       models.py
       tests.py
       views.py
```

I created manually a file call import.py  that contains:

```
from models import Category
```

In models.py that contains

```
from django.db import models
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 25, unique = True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s, %s" % (self.name, self.description)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
```

then I need to execute import.py file since shell, but I need Use models from Django.
I execute

```
python manage.py shell < .\models\import.py
```

I have this error:

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Category
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the full module name:

```
from app.models import Category
```

Or use the relative import:

```
from .models import Category # Note the dot before the `models`
```